# SQL query to filter data by a specific column value with no deduplication

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table in a clickhouse database that keeps track of items and their statuses. There can be multiple records with the same name. Each time a record is ingested it is given a status of either 0 or 1. A simplified version of the data  as follows:

| name | status |
| --- | --- |
| Obi | 0 |
| Obi | 0 |
| Harold | 0 |
| Harold | 1 |
| Ann | 0 |
| Ann | 1 |
| Lily | 0 |
| Lily | 0 |
| Lily | 0 |
| Ron | 0 |
| Ron | 1 |

I only want to display the records that have never been given a status of 1, with no de-duplication. The values returned should be:

| name | status |
| --- | --- |
| Obi | 0 |
| Obi | 0 |
| Lily | 0 |
| Lily | 0 |
| Lily | 0 |

What should the query look like in order to accomplish this?

I have tried something like this, but it returns every record that has ever had a status of 0.

```
SELECT t.*
FROM example_table t
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Name
    FROM example_table
    GROUP BY Name
) t2 ON t.Name = t2.Name
WHERE t.findingStatus=0
```

I have tried variations of the above query but have not had any luck. I was thinking maybe an inner join where the left table has `status=0` and the right table where `status` has never been `0`. Not sure how to get that to work. Any help on this is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM example_table
WHERE name NOT IN 
(
    SELECT name
    FROM example_table
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING countIf(status != 0) > 0
)
```